# I want to export my AutoCAD Layers filters to another drawing

Tags: vb.net, autocad

I work on drawings prepared by others.  At the moment, I XREF the drawings into my own template and I have my Layers and Filters set to my preferences.  However, I have to edit the XREF and create my own layers and filters within the other drawing - every time - twice a day.  I want to export my filters to the drawing.  I use AutoCAD 2014 and the option to export my filters to another drawing is not available.  Apparantly, the option was available in earlier versions of AutoCAD but not mine.  However, other Autodesk products do have this option (3DCivils, Architecture) so it is possible to export the layer filters.

I have tried to find a VBA method to do this but I have been unable to find the VBA property or method to read the filters. Moving the layers is easy, but not the filters.  The forums say there is no method.  Therefore, would it be possible to create an add-in that would manipulate the Layer Manager and create my Layer Filters.  I would have a button that would run the macro.

I suspect I will have to write a .NET routine but is what I am trying to achieve 'do-able'.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely 'do-able'.  [Kean has a very clear article covering this topic](https://www.keanw.com/2008/07/adding-and-remo.html).  Once you read them you could either serialize them to a file (like XML) for export and have another routine just for populating new drawings or if you have both drawings open, just change the database the layers and filters need to be read/written to.

Comment: Thanks. I will study the link in depth and will report back to you with my success.